# Error con post request en php slim 2 y angular, no reconoce el caracter &

Tags: json, angular7, slim

Tengo un problema a la hora de guardar una información en la base de datos. Estoy cargando unos archivos de excel con angular 7 y envío estos datos en un json a través de una petición http post. Lo raro es que si hago esta misma petición por Postman si me hace la inserción, pero cuando la hago por medio de la plataforma me arroja un error.

Lo que hice fue imprimir el json que le esta llegando pero a la hora de llegar a alguna cadena con el carácter & y esto ocasiona que el json quede incompleto cuando lo uso con json_decode();

Esta es la función que uso para enviar los datos que recibo del excel al php slim:

```
sendDataFromExcel(datos_excel){
  let json = JSON.stringify(datos_excel);
    let params = 'json='+json;
  console.log(params);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'Accept' : '*/*'});
    return this._http.post(this.url+'agregar-gestion', params, {headers : headers}).pipe(map(res=>res.json()));
 }
```

Esta es la función en el slim php:

```
$app->post("/agregar-gestion", function() use($app, $db){

$json = $app->request->post('json');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

Este es el json que le envío a la petición pasado por *JSON.stringify()*

```
json=[{"cuenta_contrato":"941594","clase_cuenta_contrato":"RES","cliente":"RIVERA ROSAS  MARIA ISABEL","instalacion":"316943","obj_conexion":"510662","tipo_via":"PJ","direccion_suministro":"5","numero":"S.N","mzlt":"MZ-G LT-10","edificio_suministro":null,"num_suministro":null,"piso_suministro":"Piso 1","con_vivienda_sum":"AAHH SARITA COLONIA","tipo_vivienda_sum":null,"detalle_cons_sum":"Etapa 1","distrito_suministro":"SAN JUAN DE MIRAFLORES","telefono":"3605744","celular":"959143855","numero_documento":"42844260","puntos_contratados":"1","fecha_registro":"11.07.2018","estado_actual":"Aprobado-Venta Nueva","fecha_firma":"5.07.2018","malla":"GN-LM-PE-SJM-S003200-MA-001","nombre_responsable_vta":"ORGANISMO SUPERVISOR DE LA INVERSION","instalador":"L & P INVERSIONES GENERALES","promocion":"19","und_predial":"1731565","zona":"Zona III","correlativo":"PENDIENTE","fecha_asignacion":"7/10/18","fecha_asignacion_cont":"7/19/18","contratista_asignado":"CONSTRUREDES ","interna_construida":"NO","trabajo_ejecutar":"ACO","supervisor_asignado":"WALTER JARA ","fusionista":"IGNACIO JARA","gabinete":"2","tc":"1","manifold":"-","fecha_asignacion_manifold":"N/A","fecha_asignacion_crd":null,"estado_asignacion":null,"tipo_gabinete":"SIMPLE ","fecha_corte":"7/26/18","fecha_gabinete":"7/26/18","fecha_tc":"7/26/18","fecha_const_manifold":"8/13/18","apl_gabinete":"SI","apl_tc":"SI","apl_manifold":"SI","estado_calidad":"TRABAJO CULMINADO","sub_estado":null,"observaciones":null,"estado_constructivo":"TODO CONSTRUIDO","clase_asignacion":null,"medita":null,"subcontratista":"GASERCOM","verifica":null,"gestion":null,"fecha_bolsa":null,"tipo_gabinete2":"EMPOTRADO ","tipo_pista":"ASFALTO","apl_pisto_cuello":"ESPECIAL","fecha_programacion":"EJECUTADO","observaciones_gsc":"EJECUTADO","eliminacion_desmote":"EJECUTADO","altitud":"EJECUTADO","longitud":"REPONER","altxlong":"POR ELIMINAR","tuberia":"CYD EJECUTADO / TC EJECUTADO / GBT EJECUTADO / MNF EJECUTADO","observacion2":"1","valoracion":"OK","liquidacion":null,"con_finalizado":null,"__EMPTY":null}]
```

Y cuando me retorna que le estaállegando en el json en el php slim me muestra esto:

```
"[{"cuenta_contrato":"941594","clase_cuenta_contrato":"RES","cliente":"RIVERA ROSAS  MARIA ISABEL","instalacion":"316943","obj_conexion":"510662","tipo_via":"PJ","direccion_suministro":"5","numero":"S.N","mzlt":"MZ-G LT-10","edificio_suministro":null,"num_suministro":null,"piso_suministro":"Piso 1","con_vivienda_sum":"AAHH SARITA COLONIA","tipo_vivienda_sum":null,"detalle_cons_sum":"Etapa 1","distrito_suministro":"SAN JUAN DE MIRAFLORES","telefono":"3605744","celular":"959143855","numero_documento":"42844260","puntos_contratados":"1","fecha_registro":"11.07.2018","estado_actual":"Aprobado-Venta Nueva","fecha_firma":"5.07.2018","malla":"GN-LM-PE-SJM-S003200-MA-001","nombre_responsable_vta":"ORGANISMO SUPERVISOR DE LA INVERSION","instalador":"L "
```

Se detiene en *"instalador" : "L "* donde allí debería de ir el & mas el resto de contenido. ¿Cómo hago para que me reconozca el &? No se si es problema del slim php o que, ayuda por favor.

Comment: Ya probaste mandarlo en código? &amp;

Comment: lo que pasa es que esa informacion son de archivos en excel, como nombres de empresas, y toda esa informacion se carga, se convierte a json, y se envia para la insercion en la bd, lo raro es que envio los mismos datos por postman y ahi si lo reconoce, entonces eso me deja pensando, que le agrega postman a la peticion para que alli si funcione?

Answer (score 1):

ya pude solucionarlo, tenia que codificar los parametros para poder que caracteres como & no generaran problema, le agregue esto.

```
let params = 'json='+encodeURIComponent(json);
```

Comment: Si... si el form lo estás enviando en formato `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` debes usar `encodeURIComponent`